# Unable to remove list item from list inside a for each loop C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a list of custom objects named `_interestlist`. Now I want to remove all the items in this list which have "active" member is set to false. and I wrote some thing like this

```
      int counter = 0;
        foreach (var interest in _interestlist)
        {
            if (interest.active==false)
            {
                _interestlist.Remove(interest);
            }
            counter++;
        }
```

But this throws an error like this

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Isn't this operation possible through a loop? IS there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated above, a foreach loop is using an Enumerator to enumerate your list, which cant be modified while iterating.

You can use LINQ instead:

```
var count  = _interestList.RemoveAll(x => x.active == false);
```

Where count is the number of elements removed.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `foreach` uses the `GetEnumerator` function. That enumerator will invalidate on changing (adding, removing, etc) the collection.

As suggested, use `for` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the collection you are iterating in `foreach` loop, use the `for` instead:

```
for (int counter = _interestlist.Count - 1; i >= 0; counter--)
{
    if (!interest[counter].active)
    {
        _interestlist.Remove(interest[counter]);
    }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't check your `bool` field like this:

```
if (!interest.active)
```

Comment: This will not work. If you need to remove elements then you must iterate backwards so you can remove elements from the end of the list.

Comment: @HABJAN Updated the code, thanks. But you can simply do `counter--` in case of removal.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to keep track of the items to remove (e.g., in another list), and then after Items has been enumerated, enumerate the removelist, removing each item from Items.

Comment: That seems double work to me.

Comment: It is, but it works... the other way is to iterate backwards so the elements are removed from the end of the list.

Comment: I like your second solution better.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through a list using `foreach` statement looks like

```
IEnumerator enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();

while ( enumerator.MoveNext() )
{
    Console.WriteLine( enumerator.Current );
}
```

You can observe that you use the same object that you got before iterating that's why you cant
modify iterated list elements in foreach statement

Answer (score 0):

**No** You can not modify the Enumerators because they are **Read-Only**

From MSDN : [`GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx)

> Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they
>   cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.

**Solution :** One solution is to iterate the items from the last to first for removing the required items.

Try This:

```
for (int i= _interestlist.Count-1; i >= 0 ;i--)
{
    if (_interestlist[i].active == false)
    {
        _interestlist.Remove(_interestlist[i]);
    }       
}
```