# Should I return an IEnumerable type, or a List?

Tags: c#

I have defined a function: `public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()`

The logic of that function goes something like this:

```
var userList = new List<User>
.. logic ...
return userList;
```

Is there a benefit of defined returning type `IEnumerable<User>` or should I just be plain about it and define return `List<User>` type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Comment: It depends what you want to do with that list. IEnumberable is way more lightweight than list.

Comment: I'd add to @ AlleXyS answer. Take a look at this [Return the most specific type, accept the most generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434385/10327189) and [When to use IList and when to use List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170/when-to-use-ilist-and-when-to-use-list).

Comment: @SayusiAndo that's wrong. IEnumerable is just an interface, you will anyway return a concrete instance of a class, that may be light or heavy. What changes is the signature of (return value of) the function: If the function returns a List, client will be able to work on it in a different way. this can be good or bad, see other suggested aswers

Comment: DO NOT USE List<T> in public API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections Take a look at guidelines you'll find a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend. It's always best to return the most restrictive type possible, but the issue with `IEnumerable` is that it's typically not meant to be enumerated more than once. For example, the `IEnumerable` may be selecting from a database, and each enumeration will start a potentially long running query.

In your case, if you're looking to return information about the user then I'd consider a `IReadOnlyList` or a `IReadOnlyCollection`

Answer (score 1):

Every collection can be implicitly converted into a IEnumerable. Indeed that happens *every time* you feed one to a foreach-loop. foreach **only** works with Enumerables. To the annoyance of everyone that runs into this Exception case: [Unable to remove list item from list inside a for each loop C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309136/unable-to-remove-list-item-from-list-inside-a-for-each-loop-c-sharp/23309168#23309168)

As you are propably finish filling the List before returning, I see no advantage to Enumerables. What they are really good at, is hiding asynchronous data retreival of some sort from the consumers. Retreival that happens **while** the Enumerable is in use. See [Directory.EnumerateFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles) for a practical example.

`List<T>` is more universal. If someone needs a `IEnumerable<T>`, they can make one from it, without relevant amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

[As Guidelines for Collections said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections):

> DO use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, a subclass of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, or
>   in rare cases `IEnumerable<T>` for properties or return values
>   representing read-only collections.
>
> In general, prefer `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. If it does not meet some
>   requirement (e.g., the collection must not implement `IList`), use a
>   custom collection by implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, or
>   `IList<T>`. If you do implement a custom read-only collection, implement
>   `ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly` to return true.
>
> **In cases where you are sure that the only scenario you will ever want
>   to support is forward-only iteration, you can simply use
>   `IEnumerable<T>`**.

and **DO NOT use ArrayList or List in public APIs**:

> These types are data structures designed to be used in internal
>   implementation, not in public APIs. List is optimized for
>   performance and power at the cost of cleanness of the APIs and
>   flexibility. For example, if you return List, you will not ever be
>   able to receive notifications when client code modifies the
>   collection. Also, List exposes many members, such as BinarySearch,
>   that are not useful or applicable in many scenarios. The following two
>   sections describe types (abstractions) designed specifically for use
>   in public APIs.

Comment: The caller will have to cast to List<T> only if actually needs to call one of its methods. If it just need to enumerate it, no cast will be required (I'm not the downvoter). In general, I prefer to return the most specific type (in opposite to accept the most generic type as input parameter): the only cons I see in this is that you will not be able to change it later without recompiling client code. According to the case, this can be more or less a problem, so affecting the choice to make

Comment: I'm not a downvoter. I fixed your link (it was broken), but this article does not recommend returning List<T> in public API

Comment: @AccessDenied thanks for your response. Please, see my updated reply. Thanks